# React Hooks useEffect saves the last state and won't update it with the new one. It runs twice with two different states

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im implementing a simple timer, and using use effect to run a function everytime my count decrements by 1.

I have a button that when pressed, changes the count state to 10 (so the idea is that if the count is currently 6, by pressing this button it should go back to 10 and start decreasing again).

The timer is working fine, but when i press the button, it creates another state, but it doesnt update the original one.

Example:

*starts count on 10*

```
10

9

8

7
```

*I press the button to go back to 10*

```
6     10

5     9

4     8
```

That's what's happening. I don't know why the useEffect gets stuck with the old state.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export default function PagTimer() {
  let history = useHistory();
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(10);

  const AddTime = () => {
    setContador(10);
  };
  const Descontar = () => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setContador(contador - 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (contador === 0) {
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      Descontar();
    }
  }, [contador]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{contador}</h1>
      <Button onClick={AddTime} variant="outline-primary">
        Add Time
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the sandbox, so it's easier to see the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-wiles-oqh71?file=/src/App.js

Comment: try clearing the timeout when `AddTime` is called. so the local. its not the issue with the useEffect its the timeout function when its using the old value in the local scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - Whenever the state is getting changed, it is creating a new timer using setTimeout without destroying the previous timer.

Solution -

You can use the cleanup function which useEffect offers (this is similar like ComponentDidUnmount function) which gets called as and when the component gets unmounted or destroyed.

```
  const Descontar = () => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setContador(contador - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return timer;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var timer;
    if (contador === 0) {
      //history.push("/");
    } else {
      timer = Descontar();
    }
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [contador]);
```

For the above to work, you would need to save/return the timer.

Or you can clear the timer in `AddTime` function

Working sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-chebyshev-kziey?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `setTimeout` is one-shot, you don't need to destroy them.

Comment: @Tethys0 Thank you! I'm gonna read about the clean interval function, so i can understand what's going on. But thanks! It is now working :)

Comment: @AKX If you can look at the code, each time the component updates, it is creating a new SetTimeout which calls back the fn "setContador" after 1sec. How is the one shot ? For each state update, it is calling back the fn which I think is useless and one should not keep such timers dangling. It's best to destroy if not being used.

Comment: Also, the code is working and there is no issue to clearing timeout, any other reason to downvote ?

Comment: `setInterval` creates a repeating timer. `setTimeout` calls the function once after the timeout. However, yep, it's good form to also destroy the timer (or React might warn about a state update to an unmounted component.)

Comment: @Tethys0 Well, for one, you're not showing the code for`Descontar` here – OP's `Descontar` doesn't return the timer handle, so you'd be calling `clearInterval(undefined)`....

Comment: Well thanks @AKX for the suggestion. I posted the working sandbox right there. Though I'll it now.

Comment: Still, you really should use the function form of `set...` as in my answer. This only works because `Descontar()` happens to get recreated with the correct closed-over (closure) value of `contador` every time the component rerenders.

Answer (score 3):

This is [covered in the React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) – you're seeing stale props. The workaround is to use a ref to "box" the value and read it from the box in the hook callback function.

The [react-use library has a handy `useLatest` hook](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLatest.md) to work around this; if you end up adding `react-use`, you could also look at e.g. `useTimeoutFn` from it.

However, in this case, the simplest fix is to use the function form to have React pass you the current `contador` value and modify it accordingly:

```
setContador(contador => contador - 1);
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a full example that uses a single interval timer:

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export default function PagTimer() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [contador, setContador] = React.useState(10);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setContador((contador) => contador - 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);
  const AddTime = React.useCallback(() => {
    setContador(10);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (contador === 0) {
      history.push("/");
    }
  }, [contador, history]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{contador}</h1>
      <Button onClick={AddTime} variant="outline-primary">
        Add Time
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: great! Thanks for the resources, will read more about it later on :)